# Imported VPN profile doesn't save group password

Tags: password, vpn

I have a *.pcf file with credentials for connect to Cisco VPN.

Importing was successful, but when I want to connect - pop-up window requires group password. I'm checking that password - it's on place and saved.

I've found the bug on this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...nc/+bug/883037, but still can't find the solution. Please help